# Include javascript var to php

Tags: javascript, php

How to include javascript **var** to **PHP** like this:

```
<script>    
var inputData = $(this).attr('id').split('_');
alertify.confirm("<?= $lang['CONFIRM_DELETE_'+inputData[1]+''] ?>");
</script>
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: You can't. Page is rendered *before* javascript is executed. You need different approach.

Comment: You need to use AJAX. PHP is all done when Javascript is running on the client.